# Loop replacing sections of a matrix with a single random generated value

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I want to replace 12 values at a time with the same number, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
ReturnsC <- matrix(NA,N,1)
x = 1
y = 12
for (i in 1:N/12){
  ReturnsC[x:y,1] <- rnorm(1,.01,N*.1)
  x = x+12
  y = y+12
}
```

thank you

Comment: Please define `N` and clarify your expected output. You probably want `for (i in 1:N)`, not `for (i in N)`, but hard to tell if there are other issues...

Comment: Now that you've switched to `for (i in 1:N/12)`, take a look at `1:N/12`. You maybe want `for (i in 1:(N/12))`

Comment: But overall, this seems like a roundabout way to get `ReturnsC = matrix(rep(rnorm(N, .01, 1:N * 0.1), each = 12), ncol = 1)`

Comment: Thank you I figured it out! I had to do N/12 - 1, N was defined as a multiple of 12